# Java process failure (hadoop, hbase)

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Anytime I am running hadoop/hbase process from a command prompt I get an error::

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 320: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 390: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 390: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java: Success
```

I get the same kind of error when I start hbase.

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Could you please tell me what could cause the issue?

Comment: Can this be permissions issue? I assume /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java does exist on your machine.

Comment: Java is installed on the machine at specified location and exported to the path

Answer (score 0):

HBase requires at least Java 6 from Oracle. 
By putting below in hbase-env.sh solved the same error 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre